# AngularJS checkbox filter

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angular-filters

I would like to filter the results.

There is a list of wines, my wish is when no checkbox is checked, the entire list of wine is displayed.

- when only 1 checkbox is checked is displayed the related category
- when more than one checkbox are checked the related categories are displayed

I'm a newbie to AngularJS, I tried with ng-model wihout success, here is the code without ng-model associated to the function:

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.10/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
                .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.wines = [
                        { name: "Wine A", category: "red" },
                        { name: "Wine B", category: "red" },
                        { name: "wine C", category: "white" },
                        { name: "Wine D", category: "red" },
                        { name: "Wine E", category: "red" },
                        { name: "wine F", category: "white" },
                        { name: "wine G", category: "champagne"},
                        { name: "wine H", category: "champagne" }

                    ];


                    $scope.selectItems = function (item) {
                        return item.category == "red";
                    };

                    $scope.selectItems = function (item) {
                        return item.category == "white";
                    };

                    $scope.selectItems = function (item) {
                        return item.category == "champagne";
                    };
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">

<h4>red: <input type="checkbox"></h4>
<h4>white: <input type="checkbox"></h4>
<h4>champagne: <input type="checkbox"></h4>



            <div ng-repeat="w in wines | filter:selectItems">
                {{w.name}}
                {{w.category}}
            </div>


</body>
</html>
```

How to use ng-model or ng-change to associate a function to each checkbox button to have a real time filtering model??

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are several implementations possible. Here's one:

1. Have a `$scope.filter = {}` object to hold the state of each filter. E.g. `{red: true, white: false...}`.
2. Associate each checkbox with the corresponding property using `ng-model`. E.g.: `input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter['red']" />`.
3. Have a function (e.g. `$scope.filterByCategory(wine)`) that decides if a wine should be displayed or not (based on the `$scope.filter` object).
4. Use that function to filter the items based on their category. E.g. `<div ng-repeat="wine in wines | filter:filterByCategory">`

---

The `filterByCategory` function could be implemented like this:

```
function filterByCategory(wine) {
  // Display the wine if
  var displayWine =
      // the wine's category checkbox is checked (`filter[category]` is true)
      $scope.filter[wine.category] ||   // or 

      // no checkbox is checked (all `filter[...]` are false)
      noFilter($scope.filter);

  return displayWine;
};
```

where `noFilter()` is a function that checks if there is any filter activated (and returns `true` if there is none):

```
function noFilter(filterObj) {
  return Object.
    keys(filterObj).
    every(function (key) { return !filterObj[key]; });
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/688/)**.

---

**UPDATE**:

I created a modified version, which supports multiple filters (not just filtering by category).
Basically, it dynamically detects the available properties (based on the first `wine` element), adds controls (groups of check-boxes) for applying filters based on each property and features a custom filter function that:

1. Filters each `wine` item, based on every property.
2. If a property has no filter applied (i.e. no check-box checked),  it is ignored.
3. If a property has check-boxes checked, it is used for filtering out `wine` items (see above).
4. There is code for applying multiple filters using AND (i.e. all properties must match) or OR (at least one property must match).

---

See, also, this **[updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wYfs4/689/)**.

Comment: ExpertSystem, thanks a lot for your answers!! It helps me a lot to understand better AngularJS. I will study your code. Really, very nice solution, thanks a again for sharing yours knowledges!!

Comment: Hi ExpertSystem, Loading the data with a json file with $http.get, all is  works fine, but in the console.log have: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. A last thing, how to put a dynamic counter of the filtered number of wines? Regards!!

Comment: @Stéphane: Take a look at the updated fiddle. I added support for originally undefined `wines` and counting filtered wines.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have to pay you a beer!! Really you helped me a lot!! Fantastic help !!

Comment: Thanks! One more time, using and analyzing your code helps me to understand better AngularJs and JS..... Have a good week-end ExpertSystem!!

Comment: Hi ExpertSystem!! How it is possible to add one or more check-box groups? For example, each group of check-box would be associated to other categories added inside the JSON file, for example category2, category3. Each group of check-box would be independent  of each others, when many check-boxes are checked, the data will be filtered. I tried, duplicating the function but, it's none working fine.  Sounds hard!! Regards, Stéphane

Comment: me too, i was tired, it was late..... Thanks for you reply, i would say to add a check-boxes group related to name. So, the check-boxes group (category) will stay, and a new one (related to name) will be created. Are you living in Greece ??I'm french living in Brazil. Regards!!

Comment: @Stéphane: Take a look at my updated answer (and demo). I am not sure I understood what you meant (but hopefully I did). BTW, yes, I live in Greece :)

Comment: Hi ExpertSystem, thanks for your very nice solution! It's exactly I needed. One more time, you help me a lot, using and analysing your works help me to manage better AngularJS and JS. Soon, I will send you the link of the wines web pages that you helps me to build! Have a nice week-end!!

Comment: Hey This is exactly what I was looking for.
 I just need to know how to do if the element as an object with more than one category, like "cat : {'white', 'red'}"

Comment: @ExpertSystem in you demo you're showing all the properties of Wine. And then you can filter them. How do I implement that without showing all the properties. Just a few of them.

Comment: @moh.ABK: I am just showing `w.name` and `w.category`. It just happens that wines don't have more properties, but if they did, the extra properties would not be shown. I am not doing anything to display all properties, I just explicitly bind to the ones I'm interested in.

Comment: This is really useful. I've been looking for something like this for some time. Would it be possible for you to create a demo of how this could be used to include a range filter as well for example filter by a set of pre-defined price range options e.g. 0-100, 100-200, 200-300 and 300+

Comment: This solution is truly great. Solves so many of my common problems with filtering like this.

Comment: Hi, could you be able to name the 4th step so I can go look it up? It looks like applying OR between an array and a function and I don't even know the name of that syntax.

Comment: @Sgene, not sure what you mean. It's all in the demo linked right below bullet 4.

Comment: Now I know that AngularJS has its own syntaxes which are far different from general languages, which answered my previous question. Another question is "<h3>{{ prop | capitalizeFirst }}</h3>." Why not "<h3>{{ capitalizeFirstFilter( prop ) }}</h3>" ? Performance reasons?

Comment: @Sgene9, actually it's just JavaScript :) The `prop | filter` syntax is indeed AngularJS-specific syntax. This is how filters work (you could have a method on your scope/controller and call it as you said, but filters are used with the `|` syntax).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add onto @gkalpak answer, I found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/magalhaespaulo/pen/jbYXPP) which allows you to provide the total amount left after an option is selected for each category.

Change the `ng-repeat` from:

```
<div ng-repeat="wine in (ctrl.wines | filter:ctrl.filterByProperties) as filteredWines">
      {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
</div>
```

To

```
<div ng-repeat="wine in filtered = (ctrl.wines | filter:ctrl.filterByProperties) as filteredWines">
  {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
</div>
```

And with the input labels add:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[prop][value]" />
    {{ value }}({{(filtered | filter:value:true).length}})
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use `filter` as `$filter`

```
app.filter('someFilter',checkboxFilter)
checkboxFilter() {
    return function (arr,filter,key,noOne=false) {
        // arr is an array of objects
        // filter is checkbox filter. someting like {1:true,2:false}
        // key is a property in ech object inside arr
        // noOne is a behavior if none of checkbox is activated (default:false)
        if (!arr.length) return null;

        function noOneCheck(filter) {
            return Object.keys(filter).every((key) => {
                return !filter[key]
            })
        }
        return arr.filter((i) => {
            return filter[i[key]] || (noOne && noOneCheck(filter))
        })
    }
};
```

**html:**

```
ng-repeat="u in project.projectTeamInvite | checkbox:project.status:'status' track by $index">
```

Comment: Wow! Did you change the accepted answer to this after 3+ years, @Stéphane?