# Angular filter with multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement multiple checkbox based filters and wondering if there is a better way to do so (something that wouldn't upset John Papa).

If I am working with Sodas and I want to filter by brand as a starting point I have this set up:

```
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.brands.Pepsi"> Pepsi
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.brands.Coke"> Coke
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="soda in vm.sodas | filter:vm.brandFilter">
      {{soda.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

with my filter function being:

```
  function brandFilter(soda) {
      if (!vm.brands) {
        return soda;
      }
      var brand = soda.brand;
      if (vm.brands[brand] === true) {
          return soda;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mP0Ji9rJONuTSZMZafRt?p=preview)

While this works I am hoping that there is a better/more production viable solution that can maintain DRYness considering I will be adding multiple 'groups' of checkboxes (if it were soda perhaps more object properties would be color, flavor, etc).

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983322/angularjs-checkbox-filter