# Multiple filters on same page - Search, Filter, Sort

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I've hit a road block. I'm trying to get these filters to

- function correctly
- play nice with one another so that I can sort the information on this page accordingly

[image: The Inventory App]

The search works fine, but I'm having no luck with the filters. These are the articles I've visited, but I've had no miraculous epiphany or 'ah-ha!' moments. I feel like the ultimate Angular scrub at the moment.

- [Help Article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058284/filter-array-using-checkboxes-with-angularjs)
- [Help Article 2](http://embed.plnkr.co/CaBpGd/)
- [Help Article 3](http://www.devacron.com/data-filtering-based-on-multiple-checkboxes-in-angularjs-howto/)
- [Help Article 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/angular-checkbox-filtering) - (this one came close for the checkbox filters, but the `$.inArray` jquery was throwing me for a loop since jquery is not included in this project)

I've been going at it for the last 5-6 hours and I'm having absolutely no luck. I need an AngularJS hero! How can I get these filters working? Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point. Code is below. Thank you!!!

[jsFiddle link to my project](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/637/)

Comment: A lot of this is angular 101 - you're missing bindings on your filter components, and on top of that, you're missing some kind of watch on said bindings. For example, your search works because you have an `ng-model` on it, and filtering your data via `ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory`

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am rather new to this stuff. Trying to learn by building. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select list ordering working quite easily - change your `ng-repeat` to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in inventory | filter: searchInventory | orderBy:sortOrder">
```

Then declare this on your `$scope`:

```
// whatever you want to be the default
$scope.sortorder = "name";
```

Then add this as the `ng-model` to your select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="sort" ng-model="sortOrder">
```

Your values on the Select List `Option` tags have to match the names of your names specified in the items in `$scope.inventory`. Use `-` & `+` for descending & ascending:

```
<option value="-price">Price</option>
<option value="lowInventory">Low Inventory</option> // not declared
<option value="+qty">Out of Stock</option>
<option value="-status">Inactive</option>
<option value="+status">Status</option>
```

Note: you will have to include own logic for `Low Inventory`.

See working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/642/).

Checkbox filtering is a bit more advanced see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983322/angularjs-checkbox-filter) for an example.

Update: I managed to get some of the checkbox filtering working using simple [ng-true-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input[checkbox]) filter.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.status2' data-ng-true-value='inactive' data-ng-false-value=''> Inactive

<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='search.status1' data-ng-true-value='!inactive' data-ng-false-value=''> Active
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/644/) for updated fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much, James! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I've ended up making a few changes thanks to your help. I noticed that since I'm already using the model `searchInventory.$` I can just piggy back off of the key/value without the addition of the filters.

Now I'm working on out of stock filter. I have the out of stock filter set to `ng-true-value='0'`, but this ends up showing items that have the number `0` present. So for example, a product with inventory `30` still shows up since it contains `0`. Any ideas on how to solve this challenge?

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/646/) is here

Comment: Thanks James. I made the changes you displayed in the jsFiddle. When I put the changes into my code it didn't seem to be working. That's when I realized there is an error in jsFiddle w. the Angular version being used. jsFiddle is using 1.2, whereas I'm using 1.5. Big oversight on my part. I have updated the `data-true` syntax accordingly, but I can't seem to figure out how to take the filter `searchInventory:!!searchInventory.qty` you provided and convert to 1.5 syntax.  [Updated jsFiddle w correct Angular](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/651/)

Comment: I am VERY appreciative of the help today. Thank you! Maybe a weird request, but what is your PayPal? I would like to buy you a pint!